# How to write a custom function in a model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is a model data:

```
class Order extends Model
{
}
```

How to write a custom method inside the `Order` class so that it can be called in constructor like this:

```
Order::myMethod()
Order->myMethod()
```

Where `myMethod` is:

```
public function myMethod() {
     return DB::query(<SQL QUERY>);
}
```

Purpose is to move SQL queries inside model's class, that don't mess this code in controllers.

Comment: Read the docs on query scopes.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . Can you provide more infomation on exactly what you need `myMethod` to do?

Comment: What you need is Repository Design Pattern.

Comment: Curious,  why not use Eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess you are asking about the static functions:

```
class Order extends Model {
     public static function myMethod() {
     }
}
```

and you can call it anywhere like

```
Order::myMethod();
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather create a custom function in Model, You can use traits to achieve the desired output.

Please follow either steps:-

- https://medium.com/@kshitij206/traits-in-laravel-5db8beffbcc3
- https://www.conetix.com.au/blog/simple-guide-using-traits-laravel-5

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired behavior using magic methods [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) and [__callStatic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic)
if your real method is static you can use `__call()` to intercept all "non static" calls and use it to call the static and use `__callStatic` to forward the calls to a new  instance to that class .

Your methods should be always static because if a non static method exists and you are calling it statically php raises an error

```
Non-static method Foo::myMethod() should not be called statically
```

No problem if your method is static

```
class Order extends Model {
    public static function myMethod() {
        return static::query()->where(...)->get(); // example
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return forward_static_call_array([__CLASS__, $name], $arguments);
    }
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array([app(__CLASS__), $name], $arguments);
    }
}

(new Order())->myMethod();
Order::myMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your exact problem is. but if you are using laravel, then you can write custom method inside the ABC model like this

```
class ABC extends Model
{
   //here is your fillable array;
   public function abc()
   {
      //Here is your Eloquent statement or SQL query;
   }
}
```

just call this abc() method inside the controller like this

```
 use ABC;
 class AbcController extends Controller
 {
     private $_abc;          // it is private variable
     // this is constructor
     public function __construct(ABC $abc)
     {
        $this->_abc= $abc;
     }
     public function abcMethod()
     {
        $this->_abc->abc();
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe I'm understanding your intention. You've stated:

> Purpose is to move SQL queries inside model's class, that don't mess this code in controllers.

Why does the `Order->myMethod()` need calling inside the constructor? If you're trying to design your data access layer to work efficiently, you can use [data repositories](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce).